# permutations of lists python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

I want to find all the permutations of a the elements in a list. 
but then with some conditions imposed.. umm..
Probably an example will help me explain better.

I have four lists

```
["1"],["0"],["a","b","c],["d","e","f"]
```

Now I want to have the permutations in following way:

```
 "10ad" ,"10bd","10cd","10ae", "10be"
 ,"10bf"..
```

and so on..

So basically every element (with every element)??
Now I know the very naive way to do this.
But what is the pythonic way to do this?
if there is any??
Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: If the order matters, please explain the ordering you want better; I would have expected "10ce" to come after "10be".

Comment: @ScottHunter: the order doesnt matter actually :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use the `itertools` module, which is part of the standard Python distribution.

For example:

```
import itertools

a = ["1"]
b = ["0"]
c = ["a","b","c"]
d = ["d","e","f"]

for item in itertools.product(a, b, c, d): 
    print(item)
```

Edit: To be clear, the `itertools.product` function provides all *combinations* for all items in the inputted lists, not *permutations*.  But based on OP's wording, I think this is what he/she actually wants.

Comment: Great answer. This returns tuples, so slight adjustment to exactly match the question would be something like:  `for item in itertools.product(a,b,c,d): print '%s%s%s'%item`

Comment: Or alternatively, if you want a list of strings, you can just `''.join(item)`