# permutations of a lists python

Tags: python, list

So I posted this question here.

[permutations of lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038604/permutations-of-lists-python)

And the solution works.. but i should have been more careful.
Please take a look at the link above.

What if I dont have a lists explicitly as a,b,c,d
but I have a list of lists.. something like

```
 lists.append(a)
  lists.append(b)
```

and so on.
And in the end all i have is "lists"

This

```
for item in itertools.product(lists): 
   print(item)
```

doesnt work in this case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking everything from a list using `*`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ["1"]
>>> b = ["0"]
>>> c = ["a","b","c"]
>>> d = ["d","e","f"]
>>> lists = [a,b,c,d]
>>> for item in itertools.product(*lists):
        print item


('1', '0', 'a', 'd')
('1', '0', 'a', 'e')
('1', '0', 'a', 'f')
('1', '0', 'b', 'd')
('1', '0', 'b', 'e')
('1', '0', 'b', 'f')
('1', '0', 'c', 'd')
('1', '0', 'c', 'e')
('1', '0', 'c', 'f')
```

This just unpacks the list into its elements so it is the same as calling `itertools.product(a,b,c,d)`. If you don't do this the `itertools.product` interperets it as one item, which is a list of lists, `[a,b,c,d]` when you want to be finding the product of the four elements inside the list.

@sberry posted this useful link: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Hi. No. basically I want to have all the permutations of the element in a list (as posted in the link).. btw what is the difference between this method and something like a+b? just curious

Comment: Hi.. Great.. it works.. but what does the "*" does?? I think  I just learnt somethign new in python :)

Comment: I wrote at the bottom what the `*` does.